# Writing a bash script to remote into a phone

Tags: bash, shell

I have couple of bash command that I want to execute and was hoping to get some help to write a script to execute them with one script if possible.

On one console, I want to execute a command `iproxy 2222 22`. The console will then print `waiting for connection`.

I'll have to open another console to execute a command `ssh -p2222 root@localhost`. Once I remote into a phone, I want to execute a simple command like `ls`.

I'm getting stuck on opening a second console and executing the command.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Thanks

Comment: Run one as a coproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several things here:

1. First, to run both the `iproxy` and the `ssh` in the same script, without having to use two different consoles you need to know how to run commands in background. This is easily done by appending `&` to the end of a command. In the next example the `iproxy` command will be run in background, and the `ssh` command will be run in the foreground at the same time:

   `iproxy 2222 22 &`

   `ssh -p2222 root@localhost`
2. Then, to execute a command over the remote shell opened by the `ssh` command you just need to include it as the last part of the `ssh` call. The next example will open a SSH connection to `root@localhost` on the `port 2222`, then it will execute a `ls` command in the remote shell, and finally it will close the SSH connection:

   `ssh -p2222 root@localhost ls`
3. Finally, to launch a new terminal and execute a command (or a script) in it, you just need to call the type of terminal of your choice, using the `-e` option with the command (or the name of the script) to be executed. The next example will open a new `gnome-terminal` and will execute the previous `ssh` example:

   `gnome-terminal -e "ssh -p2222 root@localhost ls"`

Alternatively you can open a new `kconsole` or a new `xterm` (or any other kind of terminal you may have installed in your system).

**You will notice that the terminal will close itself after executing the command**. If you need or want it to remain open, then you will have to modify the call according to the type of terminal you have opened:

- For `xterm` you will need to use the `-hold` option.
- For `kconsole` you will need to use the `--noclose` option.
- For `gnome-terminal` this is a bit more tricky. The way to do it is to create a profile, then modify the profile preferences to hold the terminal when command exits, and referencing to this profile when calling the terminal: `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command`.

Putting all together, your script should be more or less like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

iproxy 2222 22 &
xterm -hold -e "ssh -p2222 root@localhost ls"
```